# Cannot find a matching quote character for the character '''

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
 examdate = Convert.ToDateTime(ttd.DateCreated).ToString("MMM dd yy");
```

and it returns `Jun 27 18`

but I need the following output

`Jun 27 '18`

so I changed my code to

```
 examdate = Convert.ToDateTime(ttd.DateCreated).ToString("MMM dd 'yy");
```

and it threw up an error:
`Cannot find a matching quote character for the character '''.`

Comment: You may need to escape the single-quote by using `\\'`.

Comment: did you try "MMM dd \\'yy"?

Comment: Have you tried either escaping the character, or marking the string as a literal: "MMM dd \'yy" or @"MMM dd 'yy"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#escape mentions the use of backslash or surrounding the string with quote characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to escape the single quote (') inside of the ToString() call.

Simple example:

```
using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd \\'yy"));
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
Jun 27 '18
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pj7CoA)